# Как сделать function PHP и не сломать мозг

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток.
Нужна ваша помощь, вторые сутки сижу над задачей.

Суть в чем:

Есть файл (назовем его list.php) который получает данные через `$_GET` (site.ru/list.php?set=name1,name2,name3.....) Количество `name` каждый раз разное.

Затем в `list.php` через `explode` запихиваю данные в массив.
После чего я перебираю массив поэлементно, обращаюсь на сервер, в ответе с сервера получаю специальный ключ (вида `DFG3egfsG34dsfW`, у каждого элемента будет свой) и записываю полученные ключи в новый массив `ll`.

И в конце мне нужно сформировать новый адрес с этими ключами через запятую. (site.ru/load.php?id=id1,id2,id3,id4....)

Раньше, когда мне нужно было строго 5 ключей я это делал так и все работало

`$load = $link.$ll[0].",".$ll[1].",".$ll[2].",".$ll[3].",".$ll[4];`

Но так как сейчас я получаю неопределенное количество данных (от 5 до 100...) это не работает.

Нужно сделать функцию, которая будет ко количеству ключей в массиве `count(ll)`, формировать ссылку с тем же количеством `ll[]`

Простыми словами, если получу 5 значений то переменная должна быть

`$load = $link.$ll[0],$ll[1],$ll[2],$ll[3],$ll[4],$ll[5]`

если 3 значения, то:

`$load = $link.$ll[0],$ll[1],$ll[2],$ll[3]`

Если 100 значений то....

Буду очень благодарен за любую помощь!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$load = $link . implode(',', $all);
```

[документация implode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.implode.php)

Comment: все оказалось значительно проще чем я думал.